# Migrate subfolders of SVN repo to git

Tags: git, svn

Is it possible to migrate only a part of a SVN repo to Git?
Note that I have to migrate more than one folder located in the root, but not all of them.
For example given the following repo:

```
REPO_ROOT
- FOLDER_A
- FOLDER_B
- FOLDER_C
- FOLDER_D
```

I want to migrate to the Git repo only `FOLDER_B` and `FOLDER_C`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a convenient solution:

1. Clone that part of the SVN you'd like
2. Go to the root folder of your git repo
3. Type `git remote add -f tmp_repo PATH_OF_THE_SVN_CONE`
4. Type `git merge -s ours –no-commit tmp_repo/master`
5. Type `git read-tree –prefix=Demo/Kinect -u Kinect/master`
6. Commit
7. Check that everything is ok
8. Push
9. Type `git remote remove tmp_repo`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have to clone from URL of your folder and (for Git 1.6.4+) use (except others) option `--no-minimize-url`

```
git svn clone --prefix=svn/ --authors-file=authors.txt --no-minimize-url http://PEPO/PATH/TO/FOLDER/ ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Does it work also for multiple folders on the same level? See updated question.

Comment: @Maverik - why not? 2 clones with 2 different URLs into different folders

Comment: If I call it for two subsfolders I will create two local repository? Is it possible to merge them in a single one? Thanks!

Comment: @Maverik - with `--no-minimize-url` no, they will be totally unrelated. Without option they (probably, TBT) will share common `Repo_Root` and one repo can be pulled into another